# Отслеживать запросы отправляемые с компьютера

Tags: c#, requests

Всем привет, искал информацию в интернете и ничего не нашел. Мне нужно что бы приложение на **c#** отлавливало все запросы идущие с компьютера. Например: я ввожу в браузере **url**, идет **get** запрос и приложение это фиксирует(время, адрес получателя, приложение совершившее запрос). Это вообще возможно? Если нет, то возможно ли отслеживать все запросы браузеров(Chrome, Oper, ...)?

Comment: можно с помощью Wireshark

Comment: Это ближе к невозможно, из за выбора языка, смотрите в сторону си и плюсов, там это возможно, правда придется написать драйвер, но это ведь мелочи?)

Comment: Так то Fiddler как-то это делает, но он кажется подставляет свою прокси в браузер и поэтому может показывать все обращения и весь траффик.

Comment: Используйте библиотеку pcap. Есть обёртки для дотнета.

Comment: С помощью pcap можно получить из интересующего меня только время и все, под адресом получателя я имел ввиду url, не ip адрес. В идеале на выходе должно быть что то вроде (2022-04-21 16:47:52 www.google.com GET). Если есть примеры как получить url то можно ссылочку?

Comment: **Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях!** Либо редактируйте этот вопрос, либо создавайте новую тему. PS: не гоните на pcap. Полчаса назад вы не знали об этой библиотеке, а тут уже заявляете, что она чего-то не может. PPS: Вам нужно преобразовать IP в имя хоста. [Dns.GetHostEntry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-6.0)

Comment: За совет касательно вопроса спасибо сглупил. Что касается pcap, если я задаю глупые вопросы не стоит делать выводов что я совсем дебил и ничего не знаю.

Comment: Ни wireshark, ни pcap, ни raw soockets, ни даже свой драйвер не помогут, если обмен идет по https, поскольку к моменту выхода в ядро данные в пакетах уже зашифрованы. Вам нужен какой-то хук в браузер (или хакнуть либу для шифрования)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, пойду читать про хуки.